# Java - Clearing graphics from Buffered Image

Tags: java, graphics

Here is my problem:

I have a bufferedImage that acts as a base. Then, I have another BufferedImage that is an ARGB that is placed over the base. The problem is I want to clear all the graphics on the ARGB image. If I use clearRect(); then it will just put a layer of alpha over the ARGB, which will do nothing. Also, I can't use setRGB(); to control the graphics.

So my question is: how can I remove all graphics from a ARGB image?

Comment: Are you repainting the component that displays the image? Posting your code might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the right background color is set. It is used for clearing the image.

```
Graphics2d g2d = image.createGraphics();
g2d.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
g2d.clearRect(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
```

Comment: This just makes a black background, but I need it to be transparent.

Comment: I think the alpha value 255 was wrong, it should have been 0. Try the updated code.